# WPF - Making Two Expanders fill available space depending on which one is shown

Tags: wpf, xaml, mahapps.metro

So, I have 2 expanders.
One should be on the top of the control, and one should be on the bottom of the control.

When I **click the top expander, bottom should collapse**, top should expand downwards and take all the available space, without removing or pushing the bottom out of the page. And in reverse, **when I click bottom expander, top one should collapse**, bottom one should expand upwards and take all the available space on the control.

The problem I'm having is visual, I know how to bind expander's *IsExpanded* within my ViewModel and update both accordingly. What I don't know is which controls to use and how to set them up correctly.

I've tried using Grid, but If I set Row Height to *, whatever I do, their height (of course) stays fixed, and content expands only to row's allowed height.

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="2*" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <Expander
        Grid.Row="0"
        Margin="5"
        Header="Server Connections"
        IsExpanded="{Binding IsTopExpanded}">

    *** ListBox With Content ***
    </Expander>

    <Expander
        Grid.Row="1"
        Margin="5"
        Header="Server Browser"
        IsExpanded="{Binding IsBottomExpanded}">

    *** Some Content ***
    </Expander>
</Grid>
```

[image]

I've tried with StackPanel, but top Expander content doesn't receive vertical scroll bar, and therefore if I have many items - I cannot scroll down.

Hopefully I was clear enough, if I wasn't - please let me know. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to set switch between `*` and `Auto` for the `Height` of the `RowDefinition`s. You could do this using two `Style`s:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition>
            <RowDefinition.Style>
                <Style TargetType="RowDefinition">
                    <Setter Property="Height" Value="*" />
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsBottomExpanded}" Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="Height" Value="Auto" />
                        </DataTrigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </RowDefinition.Style>
        </RowDefinition>
        <RowDefinition>
            <RowDefinition.Style>
                <Style TargetType="RowDefinition">
                    <Setter Property="Height" Value="Auto" />
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsBottomExpanded}" Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="Height" Value="*" />
                        </DataTrigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </RowDefinition.Style>
        </RowDefinition>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <Expander
        Grid.Row="0"
        Margin="5"
        Header="Server Connections"
        IsExpanded="{Binding IsTopExpanded}">
        <TextBlock>*** ListBox With Content ***</TextBlock>
    </Expander>

    <Expander
        Grid.Row="1"
        Margin="5"
        Header="Server Browser"
        IsExpanded="{Binding IsBottomExpanded}">
        <TextBlock>*** Some Content ***</TextBlock>
    </Expander>
</Grid>
```

Comment: As usual, mm8 to rescue.
Thanks again!

Comment: what happens if you use more than 2 expanders though?

Comment: Wonderful answer which I've managed to steal and tweak for my own particular expander issue.